# Why are milestone amounts different for different people?

Tags: cities-skylines

My milestone for Little Hamlet requires 400 or 460 people (I don’t remember which), however I have seen Youtubers have milestone that require different numbers of people. Why?

I am playing with no mods and the Parklife, concerts, Mass Transit, Natural Disasters, and Snowfall DLCs, plus I bought the deluxe edition of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Wiki](https://skylines.paradoxwikis.com/Milestones):

> The population requirement to reach a milestone varies depending on the map selected. The exact formula is currently unknown, but it depends on the flatness of and amount of water on tiles in the central 25 with a Manhattan distance of 3 or less from the start square (including the start square itself).

For the Little Hamlet milestone, the population range is anywhere from 120 to 480.

Comment: When would it be 120 and on what map?

Comment: @Deer492 I'm not sure, but I am guessing a smaller map?